# I upgraded my project to .NET Framework 4.8 and the new package format, and now I get an error saying System.Net.Http is missing

Tags: c#

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I tried adding a NuGet reference to (a newer version of) this package but it did not help; I still get the same error... it occurs on this line of code, I think:

`private static readonly HttpClient http = new HttpClient();`

edit: here is an assembly redirect I have, I think?

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Have you got any Assembly Redirects in a config file? such as a app.config or web.config.  If so you may want to check that the redirect in the configuration is covering the version of that assembly.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions

Comment: Huh, I do have one, I think; I'll edit my post to share it. What do I need to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

In my case (after upgrade to 4.8) I forgot to remove

```
<startup>
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
</startup>
```

at the end of app.config

Answer (score 0):

This change to the binding redirect should work.

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Otherwise, I would remove the System.Net.Http Nuget package completely, then reinstall it.

Comment: Thanks, but I still get an error. However if I delete the `<dependentAssembly>` tag and its children, I can run my game!

Comment: @ekolis Thanks a lot. I had the same problem after upgrading my project to 4.8. Deleting <dependentAssembly> worked for me.